# как переименовать ключи в объекте рекурсивно

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Всем привет. Есть проблема которую пока не могу решить. В чем заключается проблема?

Есть массив объектов(например):

```
[
  {
    _id: 2, 
    _name: 'object', 
    _parent_id: 0, 
    _parent_name: '',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: 3, 
    _name: 'subject', 
    _parent_id: 2, 
    _parent_name: 'object',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: 6, 
    _name: 'foo', 
    _parent_id: 2, 
    _parent_name: 'object',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: 12, 
    _name: 'bar', 
    _parent_id: 6, 
    _parent_name: 'foo',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

мне нужно соотнести каждый дочерний объект к его родителю, вот код который это делает:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function buildTree(items, parent_id, parent_name) {
  var children, i, item, len, randStr, tree;
  if (parent_id == null) {
    parent_id = 0;
  }
  if (parent_name == null) {
    parent_name = "";
  }
  tree = [];
  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if (item._parent_id === parent_id && item._parent_name === parent_name) {
      children = this.buildTree(items, item._id, item._name);
      randStr = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      if (children) {
        item[randStr] = children;
      }
      tree.push(item);
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

вот результат который мы получим после обработки этой функцией:

```
[
  {
    _id: 2, 
    _name: 'object', 
    _parent_id: 0, 
    _parent_name: '',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    "dm62kj69v1zzt8iwwmi": [
       {
         _id: 3, 
         _name: 'subject', 
         _parent_id: 2, 
         _parent_name: 'object',
         property1: 'value1',
         property2: 'value2',
         property3: 'value3',
         ...
       },
       {
         _id: 6, 
         _name: 'foo', 
         _parent_id: 2, 
         _parent_name: 'object',
         property1: 'value1',
         property2: 'value2',
         property3: 'value3',
         "9emgjz91t04kfh5gsyvi": [
           {
             _id: 12, 
             _name: 'bar', 
             _parent_id: 6, 
             _parent_name: 'foo',
             property1: 'value1',
             property2: 'value2',
             property3: 'value3',
             ...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

результат которого я добиваюсь:

```
[
  {
    _id: 2, 
    _name: 'object', 
    _parent_id: 0, 
    _parent_name: '',
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2',
    property3: 'value3',
    subjects: [
       {
         _id: 3, 
         _name: 'subject', 
         _parent_id: 2, 
         _parent_name: 'object',
         property1: 'value1',
         property2: 'value2',
         property3: 'value3',
         ...
       },
    foos: [
       {
         _id: 6, 
         _name: 'foo', 
         _parent_id: 2, 
         _parent_name: 'object',
         property1: 'value1',
         property2: 'value2',
         property3: 'value3',
         bars: [
           {
             _id: 12, 
             _name: 'bar', 
             _parent_id: 6, 
             _parent_name: 'foo',
             property1: 'value1',
             property2: 'value2',
             property3: 'value3',
             ...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

проблема №1: все объекты с именем subject и их дочерние объекты должны быть в массиве subjects, тоже самое касается и foos и т.д. У меня пока получается что они в одном массиве.

проблема №2: вместо рэндомного имени ключа должно быть имя первого дочернего объекта во множественном числе.

Как это решить?

Comment: а почему свойство должно _subjects_ называться?

Comment: у вас там у дочерних объектов разные типы. Есть дочерний `subject`  и есть `foo`, а на выходе массив `subjects`. Я бы вам предложил  изначально не создавать рандомную строку, а не переделывать потом.

Comment: при построении дерева сложите всех потомков какой нить `children`, потом пройдитесь по дереву, и разберите их на разные массивы, в конце удаляя `children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без рекурсии. Для группировки можно использовать [функцию reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var src = [{
  _id: 2,
  _name: 'object',
  _parent_id: 0,
}, {
  _id: 3,
  _name: 'subject',
  _parent_id: 2,
}, {
  _id: 6,
  _name: 'foo',
  _parent_id: 2,
}, {
  _id: 12,
  _name: 'foo',
  _parent_id: 2,
}, {
  _id: 12,
  _name: 'bar',
  _parent_id: 6,
}];

var result = src.reduce(function(acc, el, i, arr) {
  if (el._parent_id == 0) acc.push(el); // оставляем в массиве только элементы с parentid=0
  var children = arr.filter(c => c._parent_id == el._id) // выбираем детей текущего узла
    .reduce(function(cacc, cur) { // группируем по имени
      if (!cacc[cur._name]) cacc[cur._name] = [];
      cacc[cur._name].push(cur);
      return cacc;
    }, {});

  for (var i in children) el[i] = children[i]; // вставляем сгруппированных детей в основной узел

  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему.

спасибо @teran за идею.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function buildTree(items, parent_id, parent_name) {
  var children, i, item, len, randStr, tree;
  if (parent_id == null) {
    parent_id = 0;
  }
  if (parent_name == null) {
    parent_name = "";
  }
  tree = [];
  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if (item._parent_id === parent_id && item._parent_name === parent_name) {
      children = buildTree(items, item._id, item._name);
      if (children) {
        item['children'] = children;
      }
      tree.push(item);
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

результат функции buildTree я прогоняю еще через функцию renameNodes:

```
function renameNodes(items) {
  var child, childName, i, item, j, k, len, len1, ref, tree;
  tree = [];
  for (i = j = 0, len = items.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
    item = items[i];
    if (_.has(item, 'children')) {
      ref = item.children;
      for (k = 0, len1 = ref.length; k < len1; k++) {
        child = ref[k];
        childName = _.pluralize(child._name);
        if (_.isArray(item[childName])) {
          item[childName].push(child);
        } else {
          item[childName] = [child];
        }
      }
      renameNodes(item.children);
      delete item.children;
    }
    tree.push(item);
  }
  return tree;
}
```

результат выходит такой как я и хотел.